# UITextView inside UIScrollview displays properly, but I cannot get it to respond to text input

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Layout]

I have my text views setup as such, and they display exactly as they should. I am able to scroll properly, however when I click on the text boxes, I get no keyboard and am unable to type. If I make one of the textViews the first responder, I can type, but I cannot get out of it. Tapping on the other textView does nothing, and I cannot edit text or move the cursor. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is your scroll view set to cancel Content touches? - https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619424-cancancelcontenttouches

Comment: No, it's not cancel Content touches in IB, and in code.

Comment: I am guessing you have user interaction enabled in IB and or is editable?

Comment: As I said, yes, user interaction is enabled for the UIScrollView, the UITextView, and the UIView

Comment: Are you sure there is no view overlapping the `UITextView`? You can check that in the *debug view heirarchy* if any `UIView` is on top of your `UITextView`

Comment: The debug view hierarchy doesn't work unfortunately. It just makes my app change to a blank white screen and nothing shows on the debug editor.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the scroll view was still having trouble with size ambiguity. I had assumed I could fix that later since it was displaying everything properly, but even when I placed a button inside the view that's inside the scrollview, the button didn't respond to touch either.

After fixing the ambiguity warning, it started responding properly to touch. Not sure why this is the case, but that's how I solved my problem.

Comment: My problem was a little more than just that. For any future Googlers, I thought I had solved it, but the scroll view was completely screwed up. What I finally realized the problem was was that the vertical size was completely messed up. I had to set constraints on the heights of the text view, since they are resizable, and the scrollView didn't know how big to be.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't recreate your issue mine works fine and both respond to touches. Must have been a sizing issue in IB.

[image]

Comment: Does everything scroll properly for you? I thought I had my problem solved, but now I believe the view is scrolling and leaving everything behind it. I want to check in the hierarchy debugger, but it doesn't work. I just get a blank screen and my simulator goes to blank white also.

Comment: Do you set the scrollview content size in code or in IB? You'll no doubt want to set the view that the textviews are in the same size.

Comment: I set it in IB and constrained them to be the same

Comment: My scrollView doesn't take up the whole screen, and rather the top portion attaches to a stackView filled with buttons on the top. Could you perhaps see if you have any problems with that arrangement?